# Overriding a subscript returning a covariant type in subclasses

Tags: class, swift, overriding, covariance, subscript

I have a class called `LLLinkedList`, which defines a `subscript`:

```
class LLLinkedList<L> {
    //other properties, functions and initializers...

    subscript(range: Range<Int>) -> LLLinkedList {
        get {
            //return something 
        }
        set {
            //set something
        }
    }
}
```

Now the `subscript` obviously takes a `Range<Int>` and returns a `LLLinkedList`.

I have also defined a subclass of `LLLinkedList` called `LLArray`:

```
class LLArray<A>: LLLinkedList<A> {
    //other properties, functions and initializers...
}
```

`LLArray` also implements a `subscript` taking a `Range<Int>` and returning a `LLArray`:

```
subscript(range: Range<Int>) -> LLArray {
    get {
        //return something
    }
    set {
        //set something
    }
}
```

Since `LLArray` is a type of `LLLinkedList` one can't *override* the `subscript` in the subclass (because parameters and return type are therefore the same).
If I don't override the subscript though, the compiler yells at me:

```
<stdin>:1173:5: error: cannot override mutable subscript of type '(Range<Int>) -> LLArray<A>' with covariant type '(Range<Int>) -> LLLinkedList<A>'
subscript (range: Range<Int>) -> LLArray {
^
```

Now this error makes sense to me, but how do I circumnavigate it?
Or do I even have to implement a new `subscript`?
I implemented a new `subscript`, so that a `LLArray` is returned instead of a `LLLinkedList`, in turn preventing the need for a downcast, when working with the returned instance.

Comment: You *can* override `subscript` if it is read-only (only `get`, no `set`). On the other hand, the subclass cannot override `set` with a more specific *argument* type.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Basically, there is no way to do what you want to do with read/write subscripts, as the return type of the subscript actually appears in both covariant and contravariant positions of the `LLLinkedList` class (the `get` part of the subscript places it in a covariant position; the `set` part in a contravariant position). It thus cannot change in subclasses as it would break the substitution principle. No amount of fiddling with protocols and extensions can fix it (and if it does, it's a compiler bug).

One possibility here is to split the subscript into two methods: the getter method can have a covariant return type, and the setter would still always accept the more generic `LLLinkedList` type.